# Receiving a JavaScript error: "X is not function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is, to animate and hide some div, on closerlink button click, then hide this button. Function works but doesn't hide the `closer_div` and gives error message:

> ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).animate({height: "0"}, 1000).pause is not a function

on Firefox. Actually it does all operations exc. this line  `closer_div.hide();`.

Function looks like that

```
$(closer_link).click(function () {
    ftr_form_cntr.find("div").fadeOut();
    ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).animate({height:"0"},1000).pause(2000).hide();
    closer_div.hide();
});
```

Comment: The error message says it all... `pause` is not a function. Did you mean `delay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animate function does have a callback function that will be triggered when the animation is completed, see code below:

```
ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).animate({height:"0"},1000, function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
```

What you can also do, if you want a height of 0 and have it hidden after. Use the `.slideUp()` function, this function also has a callback function.

```
ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);
```

If you want to animate, wait 1 second and do something else, do something like:

```
ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).animate({height:"0"},1000, function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        _this.hide();
    }, 1000);
})
```

Another option can be the `.delay()`, which waits 2 seconds.

```
ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).animate({height:"0"},1000).delay(2000).hide();
```

Comment: Ok solved my problem. One more Q. Can I combine theese 2 operations?     `ftr_form_cntr.find("div").fadeOut();
    ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);`

Comment: Try using: $('#element').animate({ opacity: 0, height: 'hide'}, 1000);